# Windows audio hanging

Tags: windows-7, audio

Every time I am using my computer speakers for more than half an hour, the sound suddenly stops with a small glitch and I'm unable to get it back working, except for restarting the whole computer.

When it hangs, I configure my USB audio device and do the test, but no test tone is to be heard, speaker setup configuration even hangs!

It doesn't seem to be happening when I open a certain program or whatever and it works fine until some random moment when it decides to stop.

I've tried updating the drivers and reinstalling the driver; that will restore the problem until I restart and then the sound is ffed from the moment windows had loaded.

Do note that my audio device is a USB audio device and it isn't plugged in with a jack; it's Logitech Z cinema. I´ve got an in/built soundcard on my motherboard. I'm running Windows 7.

Can anyone help me?

**Edit**: even when I switch audio device to one that is connected via jack, the problem persists. The playback devices window is not responding after I test the sound.

Comment: When the sound stops, do you hear sound via the headphones or the audio jack? This may determine if it's the USB or not!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per my comments, next time it fails, plug a device into the Jack (such as headphones or earphones)

If this makes sound, then you know the software on the PC and the sound card are fine.

Otherwise, it's the USB.

Now, the fact it starts playing suggests all speakers and cabling are OK.

Make sure you are installing the official drivers, and not the MS drivers.

You could try a different USB port.

If this continues, you need to talk to Logitech tech support.

Comment: The problem persists when switching to an audio device connect via jack. The same problem occurs. The windows playback devices window is not responding when I test audio on any device with any audio driver.

Comment: Does WMP freeze? I mean, when it plays songs, you can have it animate patterns, does this continue? @TimKuipers

Comment: I don't use WMP, but VLC and the web player I use freeze for a couple of seconds and then when I pause and unpause, it starts playback again---that is: without sound.

Comment: Can yo try WMP please, just to be sure it's not a certain desktop program